# How to get the Gallery form/section just like in Gutenberg block?

Tags: images, uploads, block-editor, gallery

I am making a custom php page in wp-admin and required to upload multiple images and display it after upload and select images to display. Basically I would like to have the same effect as in Image Gallery of Gutenberg Wordpress. Is there any function to get the whole gallery block displayed on my php page?

Thank you.

Comment: [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) is exactly that. This plugin gives you the option to add custom fields (meta data) to option panel, posts, taxonomies, even menus. This will save you a lot of time of coding everything yourself

Answer (score 2):

[`wp.media`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media) is the JavaScript API WordPress uses to display the media library modal.

You can use it yourself by enqueueing a custom JS script on your admin page:

```php
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_media();
wp_enqueue_script(
    'pb-admin-script',
    'admin.js',
    array(
        'jquery',
    )
);
```

Then work with it like this:

HTML:

```php
<button class="upload_image_button button button-primary">
    <?php _e('Upload Image', 'pb'); ?>
</button>
<img src="" id="image-preview" style="display: none"/>
```

JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.upload_image_button', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var imgPrev = $('#image-preview');

        var file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Select or upload image',
            library: {
                type: 'image'
            },
            button: {
                text: 'Select'
            },
            multiple: false,
        });

        file_frame.on('select', function() {
            var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            imgPrev.src = attachment.url;
            imgPrev.style.removeProperty('display');
        });

        file_frame.open();
    });

});
```